# is there an easy way to set destop background to a solid color in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I guess I could create a small image with the color I want and set it as the background image (tiled) or something, but surely there must be a simpler way to just say 'set desktop background to #101010'?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/change-backgrounds-pictures/?v=t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose Solid Colors for your background.

Windows have some predefined :

[image]

By choosing more in the button in bottom left corner of the window you can choose Custom color.

[image]

Comment: wow, not misleading at all... "Select Picture location" -> Solid Colors?  Guess I was assuming it was asking me to actually 'select picture location'.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a couple ways you can do this. You can go through:

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Personalization > Desktop Background

Here you can select a solid colour of your choice.

You can have a look at two methods of doing this  [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29777-background-show-image-solid-color-windows-8-8-1-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop, select personalize, scroll down the themes and select window classic.

Comment: Ah, but Windows Classic is unavailable on Windows 8!